# Ef core Access HTTPContextAccessor inside a pooled db context

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I need to access the HttpContextAccessor within the AppDbContext so that I can extract a claim.

However I got a AppDbContext that is pooled due to the concurrency requirements:

```
services.AddPooledDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>((service, options) =>
{
    options.UseNpgsql(connStr).UseLoggerFactory(service.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>());
});
```

Dependency injection doesn't work in this context, and i been looking at GetService concept but cannot figure it out.

Question is how do i now access the IHttpContextAccessor service insided my AppDbContext so that i can extract the information i need from it.